# IOS Simulator 9.0 doesn't run

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am new on IOS, using Xcode 7.0.1 and Simulator 9.0. Working on the sample project on the web. And I have a MainStoryboard as it's seen on that link.

[image: https://www.techotopia.com/images/1/1a/Xcode_5_ios_7_tab_bar_storyboard.png]

However, When I run the simulator, That shows the black screen.It looks like freeze. And I could not find any solution for that problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to project configurations General > Deployment Info > Main Interface > make sure that your storyboard is selected.
EDIT: make sure that the initial ViewController is selected as `is Initial View Controller` in `Attributes Inspector`.

[image]

Comment: couldn't find the attributes inspector. Where is exactly?

Comment: Edited my answer, try again.

Comment: At least, I have now two items on the simulator. thanx for that body, but the another problem that have occurred after editing is that there isn't any label or any text field on the simulator that I made. As I told, I have two items on simulator and each of them has textfield,button and label. but they don't seem on the simulator right now. You have any idea about it?

Comment: Give me link to your project and I will help. Have to see the source code.

Comment: found my solution, thanx men!

Answer (score 1):

From the menu, go to iOS Simulator - Reset Content and Settings.

Comment: still the same problem going on. Any solution in your mind?